# Find conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $\Omega = [-1/2, 1/2]$, and $\mathbb{P}$ be Lebesgue measure, and $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of Borel sets on $[-1/2, 1/2]$. Knowing that $X(\omega) = \omega^2$, and $Y(\omega)=I_{[-\frac{1}{2},0]}(\omega) + 2I_{[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}]}(\omega)$ find $\mathbb{E}(Y|X)$.

What I tried to do is find the density of $Y|X$, which can be denoted as $P(Y=k|X=x)=\frac{f_{X|Y=k}(x)P(Y=k)}{f_X(x)}$. The thing is I cannot find the density $f_{X|Y=k}(x)$, even though I am able to find $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$.

Any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: $P(Y = k \mid X = x)$ is by no means the _density_ of $Y$ given $X$, besides, the notation $Y \mid X$ is incorrect (although it appeared quite frequently in loose usage).

Comment: $Y \mid X$ alone is not defined (it's not a random variable!). It has to appear with $E$ like $E[Y \mid X]$, also, I would say $P((Y \mid X) \in A)$ is incorrect...

Comment: @Solitary - it's a *collection* of distributions, indexed by range of $X$. It's well defined. Do you have an alternative notation?

Comment: OK, then let me say from the standard probability text book I have read, I didn't meet your notation...

Comment: @Solitary [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Measure-Theoretic_Formulation) is a rigorous definition of what conditional probability distribution $X|Y=X|\sigma(Y)$ stands for and it agrees with what I wrote earlier.

Comment: Read carefully, the whole article doesn't have one place where $X \mid Y$ appeared **alone**.

Comment: @Solitary $X|Y$ is a collection of probability distributions $\mu(\cdot,\omega)$. It's simply a convenient/intuitive notation used everywhere. Your initial comment implied that it has no rigorous backing which is not the case.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you. That happened too many times.

Comment: @Solitary I know, but I can't pass by a strive for formalism clouding, rather than helping, understanding. If you define conditional *expectation* $E(X|Y)$ wouldn't it be natural to define a conditional *distribution* $X|Y$? If you ignore the formalism of $E(X|Y)$ and think in terms of $X|Y$, things become much clearer and intuitive as their relationship is exactly as between $E(X)$ and $X$ which fully justifies the notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, if $X(\omega) \in [0, 1/16)$, then $\omega \in (-1/4, 1/4)$, under which case $Y(\omega) = 1$ if $\omega \in (-1/4, 0]$ and $Y(\omega) = 0$ if $\omega \in (0, 1/4]$, hence 
$$E[Y|X]_\omega = (1 \times 1/4 + 0 \times 1/4) \times 2 = 1/2.$$ 
(Notice that given $\omega$ is restricted to $(-1/4, 1/4)$, the probability space shrank.) With a similar argument, we can show that if $X(\omega) \in [1/16, 1/4]$, or $|\omega| > 1/4$, then 
$$E[Y|X]_\omega = (1 \times 1/4 + 2 \times 1/4) \times 2 = 3/2.$$
In a compact way, we obtain that 
$$\boxed{E[Y|X]_\omega = \frac{1}{2}I_{[0, 1/16)}(X(\omega)) + \frac{3}{2}I_{[1/16, 1/4]}(X(\omega)).} \tag{$*$}$$

To show $(*)$ indeed gives $E[Y|X]$ rigorously, we need to check it is $\sigma(X)$-measurable (which is obvious in view of the right hand side of $(*)$ is a function of $X$) and for any $H \in \sigma(X)$, it holds that
$$\int_H \left[\frac{1}{2}I_{[0, 1/16)}(X(\omega)) + \frac{3}{2}I_{[1/16, 1/4]}(X(\omega))\right] dP = \int_H Y dP. \tag{$**$}$$
To show $(**)$, take $H = [\omega: X(\omega) \leq x] = [-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}]$ for any fixed $x \in [0, 1/4]$ as it represents a general element in $\sigma(X)$. Straightforward calculation gives that (where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure):
\begin{align}
\int_H Y dP = \sqrt{x} + 2\lambda((0, \sqrt{x}] \cap [1/4, 1/2]) \tag{1}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
& \int_H \left[\frac{1}{2}I_{[0, 1/16)}(X(\omega)) + \frac{3}{2}I_{[1/16, 1/4]}(X(\omega))\right] dP \\
= & \frac{1}{2}\lambda([-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}] \cap (-1/4, 1/4)) + \frac{3}{2}\lambda([-\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{x}] \cap [[-1/2, -1/4] \cup [1/4, 1/2]]) \tag{2}
\end{align}
Further simplification shows that both of the right hand sides of $(1)$ and $(2)$ equal to
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\sqrt{x} & 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{16}, \\
3\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{16} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{4}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Hence we are done.

Comment: According to (*) $E[Y\mid X]_{\omega}=\frac12\omega^2$ if $0\le \omega\le \frac14$. At the same time $Y(\omega)=0$ if $0\le \omega\le \frac14$. So, $\int_0^{\frac14}\frac12\omega^2\ d\omega\not =\int_0^{\frac14}0\ d\omega=0$. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: First, $E[Y|X]_\omega = \frac{1}{2}$ if $0 \leq \omega \leq \frac{1}{4}$. Second, why are you checking these two integrals are equal? $[0, 1/4]$ is not a set belongs to $\sigma(X)$.

Comment: Then what does $I_{[0, 1/16)}(X(\omega))$ mean? If $X(\omega)=\omega^2$ then I think that  $I_{[0, 1/16)}(\omega^2)=1$ iff $0\le \omega < \frac14$??

Comment: Right, that's why you got $1/2$ instead of $\omega^2/2$ ($I_A(\cdot)$ means indicator function).

Comment: Stupid of me... Right. Yet, $\frac12\int_0^{\frac14}\ d\omega=\frac18$ and $\int_0^{\frac14}Y(\omega)\ d\omega=0$ and $[0,\frac14)\in \sigma (X).$

Comment: @zoli, if so, then $\frac{1}{8} = 0$?

Comment: I am confused. Which one of the following two statements is not true: $\frac12\int_0^{\frac14}\ d\omega=\frac18$ or $\int_0^{\frac14}Y(\omega)\ d\omega=0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32089/discussion-between-solitary-and-zoli).

Comment: Why are the first two conditional expected values multiplied by 2?

Comment: As I explained in the answer, intuitively,  given $X(\omega)$ fell in that specified region, the probability space for which $Y$ lives also shrank. Take the former case for example, now the probability space is $(-1/4, 1/4)$, half of the original probability space, hence the density is $2$ instead of $1$ (this informal "partial information privided by conditioning random variable" is usually helpful to identify the form of a conditional expectation). Of course, the latter part of my answer justified this operation rigorously --- if you didn't multiply by $2$, $(**)$ cannot hold.